# android how to restrict app from starting another intentservice

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

I am having an app in which i check if there is internet every fifteen minutes.

If there is internet then i start an intent service to upload data from database to server.

```
      @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(CommonClass.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            Intent startService = new Intent(context, VitalUploadService.class);
            startWakefulService(context, startService);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Please Turn on Internet to save data to cloud",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

My question is if the **data uploading extends fifteen minutes then how can i stop the code from generating another intent service to send the data**. 
I am using  **wakefulBroadCastReceiver.**

Comment: maintain boolean in shared preference, when you start intent service then check boolean for uploading data status

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution (in my opinion) is to use some golbal/public flag:

1- you declare one variable in application (Or in other place that you can access easily).

2- Initialize it to false (the flag variable is a boolean in my sample)

3- and in your code :

```
public Boolean _bIsServiceLanched = false;//Flag variable declaration in application class for example

if(CommonClass.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {

   if_b(getApplicationContext()._bIsServiceLanched == false) {
      getApplicationContext()._bIsServiceLanched = true; 
      Intent startService = new Intent(context, VitalUploadService.class);
      startWakefulService(context, startService);
   }


} else {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Please Turn on Internet to save data to cloud",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```